# Java Firebase Get Data By Value Where

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im been stress out about this firebase, i have data like this

```
{
  "PSNPR-5I2VG" : {
  "data1" : "data1",
  "data2" : "data2",
  "data3" : "data3",
  "condition" : "false"
},
  "PSNPR-P2286" : {
  "data1" : "data1",
  "data2" : "data2",
  "data3" : "data3",
  "condition" : "true"
}
}
```

i have lot data like above, but i only get data where condition = true , so this my java code :

```
mRef.orderByChild("condition").equalTo("true").addChildEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener() {
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
 @Override
     public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot child1, String s) {

        for (DataSnapshot child2: child1.getChildren()) {
            String data1 = (String) child2.child("data1").getValue();
             Log.e("data1 "data1);
        }

     }

  });
```

i want get data1,data2,data3, from data where condition = "true", its work with where condition, but i cannot get single data by key

```
String data1 = (String) child2.child("data1").getValue();
                 Log.e("data1 "data1);
```

its error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

please help guys, im new with java android and firebase.

Comment: Create a class that matches for node. Firebase directly deserializes the node for you with getValue(object.class). The documentation is quite accurate there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Map to fetch all the data :

```
Map<String, String> dataInfo = (Map<String, String>)dataSnapshot.getValue();

for(Object info: dataInfo.values())
   {
     Map<String, String> obj= (Map<String, String>)info;
     final String data1= obj.get("data1"); 
     final String data2= obj.get("data2");
     final String data3= obj.get("data3");
   }
```